Can't render ASP.NET Identity scaffolded _Layout.cshtml
I'm having trouble rendering the custom _Layout.cshtml file from an Identity scaffold, specifically items from the Manage/ directory. The error I get is:

InvalidOperationException: The following sections have been defined
but have not been rendered by the page at
'/Areas/Identity/Pages/Account/Manage/_Layout.cshtml': 'Scripts'. To
ignore an unrendered section call IgnoreSection("sectionName").

In my Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml I have included  RenderSection at the end of my body tag:
@RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)

My Manage/_Layout.cs contains
@{
    if (ViewData.TryGetValue("ParentLayout", out var parentLayout) && parentLayout !=  null)
    {
        Layout = parentLayout.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        Layout = "Manage/_Layout.cshtml";
    }
}

<h1>Manage your account</h1>

<div>
    <h2>Change your account settings</h2>
    <hr />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <partial name="_ManageNav" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            @RenderBody()
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
}

I'm trying to access the view Manage/Index.cshtml, which also has a Script section.
@section Scripts {
    <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />
}

I access this from my _LoginPartial
<li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-dark text-white-50" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Manage/Index" title="Manage">Manage Account</a>
</li>

